# Estimator for quantile of kernel of mixture distribution

Tags: quantiles, mixture-distribution

I have a mixture distribution such as

$$ X_t = \sum_{i} w^i_t X^i_t , \quad \text{with } w^i_t \in \{0, 1\}$$
and $\sum_{i} w^i_t = 1$.

where $X^i_t$ are i.i.d  , $\forall t$. I call the $X^i$ the kernel distributions (not sure if that's the correct nomenclature).

Assuming I know $p^i_t = E[w^i_t|X_t]$, what would be a good estimator for the quantile of $X^i$?

I've got something like

$$\hat{q}^{i}_\alpha = min \{ z | \frac{\sum_t p^i_t 1_{X_t \leq z}}{\sum_t p^i_t} \geq \alpha \} $$

And I think I can prove this is a consistent estimator if $E[p^i_t]$ does not depend on $t$ $(i.e. E[p^i_t] = p_i)$.

Are there any known estimators for this kind of model (with maybe some assumptions on the kernel distributions)? Is there a general result on estimating parameters of the mixture kernels?

---

**Edit:**

This is my line of thought:

For a given function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

$$E[f(X^i)] = E[f(X_t) | w^i_t = 1] = \frac{E[f(X_t) \times w^i_t]}{E[w^i_t]} = \frac{E[f(X_t) \times p^i_t]}{E[p^i_t]}, \forall t $$

where the last equality comes from taking expectation of conditional expectation for both nominator and denominator.

So, by the law of large numbers we have that

$$ \frac{\sum_t p^i_t f(X_t)}{\sum_t p^i_t} $$

is a consistent estimator of $E[f(X^i)]$.

Using this we can get a consistent estimator for the c.d.f. of $X^i$ and then (I hope) we can prove convergence of the quantile estimator.

The thing is: I'm not satisfied with consistency and would like to understand if this is indeed a good estimator given the limited information.

Comment: Your notation is wrong, then: you have defined your random variable as a *linear combination* of random variables.  That does not create or describe a mixture distribution.  Moreover, your notation also indicates the coefficients $w_t^i$ are themselves random variables.  Really?  This is awfully ambiguous and confusing. As far as consistency goes, that's not a given: it will depend on how you determine the kernel bandwidth and how the $w_t^i$ vary as this happens.  The bandwidth needs to shrink to zero as the sample size grows.

Comment: @whuber: with the edition of the question, the observation is one and only one of the $X_i^t$'s with probability $p_i$, hence generated from the corresponding kernel with probability $p_i$. I would thus qualify the distribution as a genuine mixture. The $\omega_i^t$ are the latent component indicators.

Comment: @Xi'an: you're absolutely correct. This was a typing mistake on my part. Just corrected it, there were some $i$'s where they should not be

Comment: I would think you need to estimate the posterior probability that $X_t^i=X_t$ and this would require to know the distributions of the components. Otherwise, I do not think the problem can be solved...

Comment: Yes, this is true. I'm assuming in this case that I know the posterior probabilities without knowing the kernel distributions. In reality I have different ways of generating the probabilities and want to find the parameters of the inner distributions that "best match" my probabilities, given the samples. Without making too many assumptions.